# How to set a start time and end time for the simulation in Simulink?

Tags: simulink

I am currently doing a modeling in Simulink and I am facing a problem. Since this model is using time as input, I need to set a specific time for it. For example, I set the starting time as 9 am and the ending time is 5 pm. The model will get current time every 15 minutes and use the current time as an input until it reach 5 pm. For example, now is 9 am and the model get the time and run the calculation. After 15 minutes is 9.15 am, the model get the time and run the calculation using the current time as input until it reaches 5 pm. Is it possible to do that in Simulink?

Comment: Asking is something is possible would likely receive a yes/no answer. It may not very helpfull, you should consider trynig to do it and if you face any error/problem create a [mcve] so you could get proper help.This link could also be useful https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Since I dunno where to start so I asked this question. If someone give me a starting point then I would try to do it by myself and figure it out. =)

Comment: Can you show how you use time as an input? You can define the start/stop time for a model but it is difficult to advise on the correct way without knowing how you use time as an input? Do you mean the (Clock)[https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/clock.html] block?

Comment: Actually it is local time, I use the local time to calculate the sun position. The hour will be in 24 hours form. For example, 13:15 is the input of the time. (1.15pm)

Comment: From your description it isn't clear whether you want to literally run your model at 15 minute intervals throughout the day (i.e. the clock on your computer says 9am, so you run the model once, then the clock on your computer says 9:15am so you run the model again, etc. until 5pm), or whether you want to simulate your model, which may only take seconds, as if it is getting 15minute time intervals as its input.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Digital Clock block in Simulink.
It gets Output simulation time at specified sampling interval.

You can find more detail in

https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/digitalclock.html

Comment: I will try it =) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you actually want the "real local time" you can use a MATLAB function inside your simulink model

```
function [hr,mn,sec]= GetLocalTime
    eml.extrinsic('now');
    eml.extrinsic('datestr');
    eml.extrinsic('datetime');
    eml.extrinsic('str2num');

    hr = 0;
    mn = 0;
    sec = 0;

    nw = datetime('now');
    hr = str2num(datestr(nw,'HH'));
    mn = str2num(datestr(nw,'MM'));
    sec = str2num(datestr(nw,'SS'));
end
```

If you create this inside a simulink 'MATLAB function' block, it will create a block with 3 outputs to represent hours, minutes and seconds of the current PC time.